# TypeError: require(...).App is undefined

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've added this code to web/static/js/app.js,

```
export var App = {
  run: function(){
    console.log("Hello!")
  }
}
```

Then add this in web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

```
<script>require("web/static/js/app").App.run()</script>
```

Then refresh the browse its showing this in console:

```
TypeError: require(...).App is undefined
<script>require("web/static/js/app").App.run()</script>
```

Some one please tell me how to finish it.

Comment: Did you put it below this line `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>`

Comment: yes, thats my code   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
    <script>require("web/static/js/app").App.run()</script>

Comment: @Carey do you see a line containing `require.register("web/static/js/app.js"` in http://localhost:4000/js/app.js (or wherever you're running it)?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes Its contains

Comment: @Carey and does it contain `var App = { ... run: function() { console.log ... } ... }`? What's the value of `require("web/static/js/app")` in the browser console? (The code in the question works fine for me.)

Comment: Can confirm this should work, double check if everything is in order and make sure brunch compiled `app.js` correctly

Comment: @Dogbert Did you mean this `require.register("web/static/js/app.js", function(exports, require, module) { ` contain `var App ...  ` ? , its not contain , i've brunch compiled it , but still so.